# NetBeans 20 issue

Tags: netbeans, ide

i just downloaded netbeans and i tried to create a basic html document with marven, now maybe im doing something wrong but everytime i run it this is the error message im getting, any help?

"Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.3.0 (absent): org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.3.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] [http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException"](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException%22)

Im not sue what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can let Maven retry the download by passing the -U parameter:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Beside that: version 2.3.0 is ancient as it was released on 28.09.2012. The current version is 3.4.0.

And if this all does not help: post your pom.xml.